# How can I add a space after a specific character in a string?

Tags: python, string, join

I need to add a space between X in a string. The program takes measurements in one field and I need to be able to separate integers from the "x" before doing the calculation.

For example: "12x24" should read "12 x 24"

Comment: how that answer or even the question is similar to mine? not at all in my opinion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `'x'` with `'<space>x<space>'` using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) function as:

```
>>> my_str = '12x24'
>>> my_str.replace('x', ' x ')
'12 x 24'
```

Comment: excellent, that did the trick. so simple yet I couldnt come up with it. thx.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `replace` method to substitute `' x '` for `'x'`:

```
string.replace('x', ' x ')
```